# MySQL - use result of nested stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is there any way to use the return value of a stored procedure in another stored procedure?

Just a very basic theoretical example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `user_read_name_and_email` (
    IN `param_user_id` INT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE `current_user` SET;
    SET `current_user` = CALL `user_read`(`param_user_id`);
    SELECT `user_name`, `user_email` FROM `current_user`;
END


CREATE PROCEDURE `user_read` (
    IN `param_user_id` INT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `user_id` = `param_user_id`;
END
```

Comment: You can get the output as a cursor, and loop through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the one and only workaround is to use temporary tables.

Your example would be possible in MS SQL Server 2008 - there you can assing output of stored procedure to some variable.